# Any way to see how many questions with certain tag(s) are in the close vote queue?

Tags: support, tags, vote-to-close, data-explorer

I just recently started using the filtering options for the close vote review queue. I really like it.

I was searching the data explorer to see if there was currently any methods to see how many questions are in the close vote review queue for a certain tag, but wasn't able to find anything.

I think it would be useful to me and others, if not at least just very interesting to see which tag(s) have the most or least questions in the close vote review queue.

For example, if say a question is tagged with [css](/questions/tagged/css)  and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) , I would like to see how many of these questions are in the close vote queue.  So that if I choose to filter by questions containing both those tags, I can then determine how much progress I'm making at clearing those up, and hopefully get them down to 0 if realistically possible. **Plus I'd have a better sense of accomplishing something, instead of just always seeing the close vote review queue being increased no matter what we do.** *On a sidenote: I do think that at least trusted users or even 10kers should get 150 or so close votes per day.*

Comment: Got it, I missed that.  I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to use the Data Explorer to get this instead of having this added to the close review queue, then you should be able to use the following query that I just threw together:

```
select row_number() over (order by p.id),
  p.id AS [Post Link], p.tags
from posts p
inner join votes v
  on p.id = v.postid
inner join posttags pt
  on p.id = pt.postid
inner join tags t
  on pt.tagid = t.id
where v.votetypeid = 6
  and p.closeddate is null
  and t.tagname = ##Tag:string?tagname##
  and p.viewcount < 100
```

The query is available [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/167625/questions-with-close-votes-by-specific-tag).  It should get you started.

If you want to search by multiple tags, then you can use the following which is also [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/167634/questions-with-close-votes-by-tag-multiple-tags-same-question):

```
select row_number() over (order by p.id),
  p.id AS [Post Link], 
  p.tags
from posts p
inner join votes v
  on p.id = v.postid
inner join posttags pt
  on p.id = pt.postid
inner join tags t
  on pt.tagid = t.id
where v.votetypeid = 6
  and p.closeddate is null
  and t.tagname IN (##Tag1:string?tagname##, ##Tag2:string?tagname##)
  and p.viewcount < 100
group by p.id, p.tags
having count(distinct t.tagname) >= 2;
```

Comment: MM... this would be the best if it was a list of all the questions per tag, kinda like shog showed us the other day.

Comment: @Braiam The data explorer is available to anyone, feel free to update the query to get it to return any additional info.  I quickly wrote this as a start to what was asked for.